# Extract data from html

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I have a scraper class, what collects players from a popular odds portal.
The exact first names are not present, the site uses short forms. eg Rafael -> R. Fortunately they can be found in the links in slugified form (nadal-rafael)

I made a method `processPlayers`, what tries solve this. It works in simpler cases, but fails if the player have hyphen in his/her first name or she/he has two first names.

I wrote some tests to demonstrate the html structure, and the problem.

```js
class Scraper {
  /**
   * Converts a html string to a cheerio object
   * @param {String} html The html string
   * @return {Object} The cheerio object
   */
  htmlToDom(html) {
    return cheerio.load(html)
  }
  /**
   * Gives back the number of parts if the name would slugify
   * It takes in account, that the name could contains hyphen
   * Leopold von Sacher-Masoch -> leopold-von-sacher-masoch
   * @param {Array} a_name The name splitted by space (' ')
   * @return {Integer} The length of the name
   */
  getNameLength(a_name) {
    let name = a_name.length > 1 ? a_name.join(' ') : a_name[0]
    return a_name.length + name.split('-').length - 1
  }

  capitalize(a_name) {
    let res = []
    a_name.forEach(str => {
      res.push(str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1))
    })
    return res.join(' ')
  }

  processPlayers(players) {
    let link = players('a')
    let href = link.attr('href')
    let a_players = link.text().split(' - ')
    let a_href = href.split('/')
    let a_link = a_href[a_href.length - 2].split('-')
    let a_player1 = a_players[0].trim().split(' ')
    let a_player2 = a_players[1].trim().split(' ')
    let a_player1_lastName = a_player1.slice(0, -1)
    let a_player2_lastName = a_player2.slice(0, -1)
    let a_player1ShortFirstName = [a_player1[a_player1.length - 1]]
    let a_player2ShortFirstName = [a_player2[a_player2.length - 1]]

    let p1_lnLength = this.getNameLength(a_player1_lastName)
    let p1_fnLength = this.getNameLength(a_player1ShortFirstName)
    let p2_lnLength = this.getNameLength(a_player2_lastName)
    let p2_fnLength = this.getNameLength(a_player2ShortFirstName)
    let p1_length = p1_lnLength + p1_fnLength
    let p2_length = p2_lnLength + p2_fnLength
    let player1FirstName = this.capitalize(a_link.slice(p1_lnLength, p1_length))
    let player2FirstName = this.capitalize(a_link.slice(p1_length + p2_lnLength, p1_length + p2_length))

    return {
      p1: {
        firstName: player1FirstName,
        lastName: a_player1_lastName.join(' ')
      },
      p2: {
        firstName: player2FirstName,
        lastName: a_player2_lastName.join(' ')
      }
    }
  }
}

// test ===========================================================


test('simple case', function() {
  let playersCell = `
    <td>
      <a href="/t/pavlyuchenkova-anastasia-sorribes-tormo-sara/">
        <span>Pavlyuchenkova A.</span>
         - Sorribes Tormo S.
       </a>
    </td>
    `
  const scraper = new Scraper()
  const td = scraper.htmlToDom(playersCell)
  const players = scraper.processPlayers(td)

  equal(players.p1.firstName, 'Anastasia')
  equal(players.p1.lastName, 'Pavlyuchenkova')

  deepEqual(players.p2, {
    firstName: 'Sara',
    lastName: 'Sorribes Tormo',
  })
});

// =====================================================================

test('hyphen in last name', function() {
  let playersCell = `
    <td><a href="/t/kudermetova-veronika-duque-marino-mariana/">
      <span>Kudermetova V.</span> - Duque-Marino M.</a>
    </td>
    `
  const scraper = new Scraper()
  const td = scraper.htmlToDom(playersCell)
  const players = scraper.processPlayers(td)

  equal(players.p2.firstName, 'Mariana')
  equal(players.p2.lastName, 'Duque-Marino')
});

// =====================================================================

test('hyphen in first name', function() {
  let playersCell = `
    <td>
      <a href="/t/tsonga-jo-wilfried-mayer-florian/">
        <span>Tsonga J-W.</span>
        - Mayer F.
      </a>
    </td>
    `
  const scraper = new Scraper()
  const td = scraper.htmlToDom(playersCell)
  const players = scraper.processPlayers(td)

  equal(players.p1.firstName, 'Jo-Wilfried')
  equal(players.p1.lastName, 'Tsonga')
});

test('two first names', function() {
  let playersCell = `
      <td>
        <a href="/t/alexandrova-ekaterina-muguruza-blanco-garbine/">
        Alexandrova E. - <span>Muguruza</span> B. G.</a>
      </td>
    `
  const scraper = new Scraper()
  const td = scraper.htmlToDom(playersCell)
  const players = scraper.processPlayers(td)

  equal(players.p2.firstName, 'Blanco Garbine')
  equal(players.p2.lastName, 'Muguruza')
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/cheerio@latest"></script>
  <link rel="StyleSheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It looks like stackoverflow's snippet has some problem with qunit. So here is the JsBin link:

http://jsbin.com/tohafiqivo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is to determine the `last name` and the `first name` correctly in the 'difficult' cases.

You're splitting the text in two full names, OK.
Then you're splitting full name in several words, OK.

And then you're making a mistake assuming that the `first name` is always the last word, and the rest is the `last name`.

In fact, the `last name` is all the words which are not in the short form, and the rest is the `first name`.

I've solved your problem this way.

Please find the updated `class Scraper` below (I've removed the functions which are not in use anymore):

```
class Scraper {
  /**
   * Converts a html string to a cheerio object
   * @param {String} html The html string
   * @return {Object} The cheerio object
   */
  htmlToDom(html) {
    return cheerio.load(html)
  }

  processPlayers(players) {
    let href = players('a').attr('href')
    let N = players('a').text().trim().split(/\s+-\s+/).map(n => {
        let r = new RegExp('.+('+n.replace(/-/g,'\\S+').replace(/\./g,'[^-]+').replace(/\s/g,'.')+').+','i')
        let p = {lastName: n.replace(/\s\S+\./g,'')}
        href.match(r).map(m => {
          r = new RegExp(p.lastName.replace(/\s/g,'.') + '-', 'i')
          m = m.replace(r,'').split(/-/).map(i => {return i.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + i.substring(1)})
          p.firstName = n.split(p.lastName + ' ')[1].replace(/\./g,'').split('').map(l => {return m[0] && m[0].indexOf(l) === 0 ? m.shift() : l}).join('')
        })
        return p
      })
    return {p1: N[0], p2: N[1]}
  }
}
```

It passes all the tests.
Sorry if it's not very readable.

Comment: it is hard to read and to understand, but a very compact (working) solution :)